# Unable to Print instance id using Boto3

Tags: python, boto3

I was trying to print the InstanceId followed by the VolumeID and state. I am able to print the 'VolumeID' and 'state' but I am getting an 'KeyError' while trying to print the 'InstanceID'. Not sure on what I am doing wrong here.

```
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
volumes = ec2.describe_volumes()

for i in volumes['Volumes']:
    print(i['InstanceId'])
    print(i['VolumeId'])
    print(i['State'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The `InstanceId` for the volume is on its [`attachments` property](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html?highlight=attachment%20volume#EC2.Volume.attachments), which is a `list` you can iterate through:

```
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
volumes = ec2.describe_volumes()

for i in volumes['Volumes']:
    for a in i['Attachments']:
        print(a['InstanceId'])
    print(i['VolumeId'])
    print(i['State'])
```

Comment: I tried this but this returns the error 'AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'attachments'




```
    for a in i.attachments:
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'attachments'
```

Comment: @AvikChowdhury Sorry, updated my answer - it should be a dict key access for the key `["Attachments"]`.